# Calculating individuals turning specific age within a few months from current date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write a query where I can calculate individuals that will be turning 65 based on their birth date while using the current date(GETDATE). However, the query also requires that I be able to pull individuals who will be turning 65 within 3 months of the current date(GETDATE). So far, I've only been able to pull individuals by entering a parameter of 19 into my century field (eebdcy) and entering 52 in my year field (eebdyr). I would like to remove these 2 fields and allow the user to just run the query without having to fiddle with my date fields. Is this possible?

Thank you in advance.

My Code:

```
SELECT                                                              
distinct eessn AS SSN, eenaml AS LastName, eenamf AS FirstName, eenamm AS MiddleInitial,                               
         ( RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(varchar, EEBDCY), 2) + RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(varchar, EEBDYR), 2) + '-' + RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(varchar, EEBDMT), 2) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar, EEBDDY), 2) ) AS [DOB],      
         phprid AS ProductID, phacct AS AccountNumber, amplac AS  AccountName, amua12 AS MSPInd, phgrp AS GroupID,                       
         ( RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(varchar, amfxc2), 2) + RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(varchar, amfxy2), 2) + '-' + RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(varchar, amfxm2), 2) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar, amfxd2), 2) ) as MSPEFFDT,   
         substring(amuaky,1,3) as REP,
         CONVERT (date, GETDATE()) AS [TODAY],
        CAST(DATEDIFF(DD,( RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(varchar, EEBDCY), 2) + RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(varchar, EEBDYR), 2) + '-' + RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(varchar, EEBDMT), 2) + '-' + RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(varchar, EEBDDY), 2) ), GETDATE())/365.25 AS INT) AS AGE   
    FROM pdthist, empmstr, actmstr         
   WHERE phgrp in ('4664 ESP','4664 XM')                              
     and phpcat = 3 and phtdcy = 0                                    
     and eessn = phssn and eegrp = phgrp                              
     and phacct = amacct and phgrp = amgrp and amtdcy = 0   
     and eebdcy = 19 and eebdyr = 52                                      
    ORDER BY phacct, eessn
```

Comment: by the way, you should stop using commas between table names in the from clause, this will force you into using proper SQL join syntax.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks again for the assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this would work:

```
select
*
from your_table
cross apply (
    select DATEFROMPARTS((EEBDCY + EEBDYR), EEBDMT, EEBDDY), dateadd(month,3,getdate())
    ) ca (Birthdate, CompareDate)
where 65 <= YEAR(CompareDate) - (EEBDCY + EEBDYR)
            - ( CASE
                   WHEN MONTH(EEBDMT) > MONTH(CompareDate)
                     OR ( MONTH(EEBDMT) = MONTH(CompareDate)
                        AND DAY(EEBDDY) > DAY(CompareDate)
                        )
                   THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
                 END )
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c72dc6/4)

```
CREATE TABLE your_table
    ([EEBDCY] int, [EEBDYR] int, [EEBDMT] int, [EEBDDY] int)
;

INSERT INTO your_table
    ([EEBDCY], [EEBDYR], [EEBDMT], [EEBDDY])
VALUES
    (1900, 50, 3, 13),
    (1900, 50, 12, 31),
    (1900, 51, 3, 13),
    (1900, 51, 12, 31),
    (1900, 52, 3, 13),
    (1900, 52, 12, 31),
    (1900, 53, 3, 13),
    (1900, 53, 12, 31),
    (1900, 54, 3, 13),
    (1900, 54, 12, 31),
    (1900, 49, 3, 13),
    (1900, 49, 12, 31),
    (1900, 64, 3, 13),
    (1900, 64, 12, 31)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
      *
      , YEAR(CompareDate) - (EEBDCY + EEBDYR)
            - ( CASE
                   WHEN MONTH(EEBDMT) > MONTH(CompareDate)
                     OR ( MONTH(EEBDMT) = MONTH(CompareDate)
                        AND DAY(EEBDDY) > DAY(CompareDate)
                        )
                   THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
                 END ) as Age
from your_table
cross apply (
    select DATEFROMPARTS((EEBDCY + EEBDYR), EEBDMT, EEBDDY), dateadd(month,3,getdate())
    ) ca (Birthdate, CompareDate)
where 65 <= YEAR(CompareDate) - (EEBDCY + EEBDYR)
            - ( CASE
                   WHEN MONTH(EEBDMT) > MONTH(CompareDate)
                     OR ( MONTH(EEBDMT) = MONTH(CompareDate)
                        AND DAY(EEBDDY) > DAY(CompareDate)
                        )
                   THEN 1
                   ELSE 0
                 END ) 
order by birthdate
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c72dc6/4/0)**:

```
| EEBDCY | EEBDYR | EEBDMT | EEBDDY |  Birthdate |              CompareDate | Age |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|------------|--------------------------|-----|
|   1900 |     49 |      3 |     13 | 1949-03-13 | 2018-03-06T03:14:52.793Z |  69 |
|   1900 |     49 |     12 |     31 | 1949-12-31 | 2018-03-06T03:14:52.793Z |  69 |
|   1900 |     50 |      3 |     13 | 1950-03-13 | 2018-03-06T03:14:52.793Z |  68 |
|   1900 |     50 |     12 |     31 | 1950-12-31 | 2018-03-06T03:14:52.793Z |  68 |
|   1900 |     51 |      3 |     13 | 1951-03-13 | 2018-03-06T03:14:52.793Z |  67 |
|   1900 |     51 |     12 |     31 | 1951-12-31 | 2018-03-06T03:14:52.793Z |  67 |
|   1900 |     52 |      3 |     13 | 1952-03-13 | 2018-03-06T03:14:52.793Z |  66 |
|   1900 |     52 |     12 |     31 | 1952-12-31 | 2018-03-06T03:14:52.793Z |  66 |
|   1900 |     53 |      3 |     13 | 1953-03-13 | 2018-03-06T03:14:52.793Z |  65 |
|   1900 |     53 |     12 |     31 | 1953-12-31 | 2018-03-06T03:14:52.793Z |  65 |
```